# Adding selected objects to active keying set

Tags: python, keyframes

I'm trying to add selected objects to active keying set but it doesn't work (no error). This is my script:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

ks = scene.keying_sets.active

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    ksp = ks.paths.add(obj.id_data, obj.id_data.name+'.location', index=-1)
```

Where am I wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I finally found in the scene panel that the data path should just be "location", so my code sould be:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

ks = scene.keying_sets.active

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    ksp = ks.paths.add(obj.id_data, 'location', index=-1)
    ksp = ks.paths.add(obj.id_data, 'rotation_euler', index=-1)
    # "rotation_quaternion" for quaternion mode
```

Now it works !